# Numerical Laplace Transform of InterpolatingFunction

Tags: numerical-integration, interpolation, integral-transforms

What are some ways to find the numerical Laplace transform of an InterpolatingFunction? (I know that numerical Laplace transforms are rarely used but my application requires a numerical evaluation). Thanks in advance for any help -- I'm relatively new to Mathematica and would really appreciate it!

Comment: The problem is for each s you need to do an integral. You could use Fourier transforms and weight your interpolation function with `Exp[-a t]` . This should be fast. The kernel of the integration would be `Exp[-(a +I  w )t]' which is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the definition of `LaplaceTransform` and using `NIntegrate` is a possiblity:

```
(* 1d case *)
nlap[f_, s_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[t] Exp[-s*t], {t, 0, ∞}]
```

The multi-dimensional case is a bit harder - I think this does the trick though:

```
(* multidimensional case *)
nlapnd[f_, s_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := 
 With[{vars = Array[t, Length@s]},
  With[{dots = vars.s, g = Apply[f, vars]},
   NIntegrate[g*Exp[-dots], 
    Evaluate[Sequence @@ ({#, 0, ∞} & /@ vars)]]]
  ]
```

This simple test case below for `f[x]:=x^2` with `LaplaceTransform` `2/s^3` shows the numerical one matches the analytic one, so I think my implementation is correct, at least for 1D:

```
f[x_] := x^2
(* make some data and the interpolation function *)
data = Table[f[x], {x, 1, 5}];
intp = Interpolation[data];

(* show that they match up *)
Show[
 ListPlot[data],
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}]
 ]

(* get the laplace transform *)
lp = LaplaceTransform[f[x], x, s]
(* result: 2/s^3 *)

(* verify the error is very small between lp transform of f[x] and the numerical 
   transform of the interpolation function.  *)
Plot[nlap[intp, s] - lp, {s, 0, 3}]
```