# Numerical Definite Integral of Numerical Laplace Transform

Tags: numerical-integration, warning-messages, interpolation, integral-transforms

I'm having problem taking the numerical definite integral of a numerical Laplace transform that depends on two variables due to NIntegrate:inumr errors:

```
nlap1[f_, u_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[f[u, t] Exp[-s*t], {t, 0, ∞}]
coshint[s_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[Cosh[Sqrt[s]*u]*nlap1[intertau, u, s], {u, 0, 1}]
```

Modifying the wonderful suggestion of flinty in [Numerical Laplace Transform of InterpolatingFunction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/225341/numerical-laplace-transform-of-interpolatingfunction/225365#225365), `nlap1` takes the numerical Laplace transform of an InterpolatingFunction `intertau` that is a function of both u and t but ONLY transforms the variable t. `coshint` attempts to take the numerical definite integral with respect to u but no matter what values are entered, I get the error NIntegrate: The integrand [e^(-random number*t) in `nlap1`] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region {{}}. However, `nlap1` itself seems to work fine for the most part.

It's important to note that the region specified in the error is outside of the range of the InterpolatingFunction `intertau`, but I didn't think this would really matter? I was wondering if anyone had any suggestions for changing `coshint` so that it accomplishes its intended purpose -- again, Mathematica is quite new to me so I'd greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: `intertau` shouldn't take u as a parameter right. You changed the definition of nlap1 to add f[u, t] but this is incorrect - it should be f[t]

Comment: Thanks for your response! I changed `nlap1` back to what you originally suggested with only f[t] and called that version in `coshint` but am still getting the same error unfortunately -- is that what you meant?

Comment: If your interpolation is 1d and has no dependence on `u` then change `nlap1[f_, u_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ]` to `nlap1[f_, s_?NumericQ]`, change `f[u,t]` to `f[t]` and change `NIntegrate[Cosh[Sqrt[s]*u]*nlap1[intertau, u, s], {u, 0, 1}]` to `NIntegrate[Cosh[Sqrt[s]*u], {u, 0, 1}]*nlap1[intertau, s]`

Comment: Yep that's what I did, but my interpolation `intertau` is 2d and does have a dependence on `u` but `u` isn't transformed -- only `t` is (so the Laplace transform only transforms one variable)

Comment: I see now, have you tried changing f[u,t] to f[{u,t}] in your original code ?

Comment: I just tried that and I'm getting the same errors, along with additional errors that the integrand in `coshint` is also not numeric for a certain value of `u`. I'll keep trying things but thanks so much for your help!

Comment: When you use your interpolation function on its own what do you get?. A number or a list? If it's a list then that's wrong. If I had `intertau` or a simplified version of it, then it might be easier.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but I've decided to table this problem for a later date, but many thanks again for all of your help @flinty!